# how to populate a 2d array with random alphabetic values from a range

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm fairly new to java programming and i  would like to create two methods: 
method 1 would generate a 2d array 5*5 and populate it with values between a-e 
method 2 would just print the result to the screen 
i  understand the iterating over the array using the two for loops and printing it in one go but splitting it up has me a bit confused.
what i have so far this is my first method

```
       public void create()
         {
              Random r = new Random();  
              char Type[] = {'a','c','e','d'};

             for (int i = 0; i<seats.length; i++)
             {
                 for (int j = 0; j<seats[i].length; j++)
                {
                    seats[i][j] = Type[r.nextInt(Type.length)];
                }
            }

         }
```

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to have the array created outside of the method. I would suggest a global variable to avoid the pass-by-value memory inefficiency issue.

```
 import java.util.Random;
 public class alpha_array
 {
     char array[][] = new char[5][5];
     Random rnd = new Random();

     public static void main(String[]args)
     {
         populate_array();
         print_array();
     }
 }
```

Next your going to need your two functions. For the population of the array, don't forget to import util at the top of your code:

populate_array():

```
public void populate_array()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            int x = rnd.nextInt(5); //0 to 4
            switch(x){
                case 0:{
                    array[i][j] = 'a';
                    break;
                }
                case 1:{
                    array[i][j] = 'b';
                    break;
                }
                case 2:{
                    array[i][j] = 'c';
                    break;
                }
                ...ETC
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally just mimic the same structure for the print_array method, except instead just use:

```
System.out.print(array[i][j]);
```

for each line. Hope this helps.

Comment: Good answer, but consider having the create function return an array instead of being void and working off the global namespace.  Also, instead of a switch statement you can use character arithmetic e.g. `array[i][j] = 'a' + rnd.nextInt(5);`.  Lastly, naming using underscores is non-standard for Java and camel case is preferred e.g. `populateArray()` vs `populate_array()`.

Comment: increment1's improvements are notable - I'd follow his advice.